# Swift: Errors when using different integer sizes

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

I've been trying out Swift, since it's obviously the direction that Apple wants us to go in.
However, I've been really annoyed with the fact that you can't seem to add integers of different sizes:

```
    var a: Int64 = 1500
    var b: Int32 = 12349

    var c = a + b
    if a < b { ... }
```

The yielded error is "Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied argument' — obviously since they are object types. None of the class methods seem to be of any help in up/down-converting integers.

Same situation applies with any of the type aliases, obviously, (CInt + CLong).

I can see a lot of real-world situations where it is immensely practical to be able to do integer arithmetic let alone comparisons or bitwise operations on two disparately-sized integers.

How to solve this? Explicit casting with the **as** operator doesn't seem to work. The Swift language book isn't much help either as it doesn't really discuss this scenario.

Comment: var c = Int(a) + Int(b)

Answer (score 7):

The Swift language book does discuss this scenario in the chapter “Numeric Type Conversion”:

```
let twoThousand: UInt16 = 2_000
let one: UInt8 = 1
let twoThousandAndOne = twoThousand + UInt16(one)
```

> Because both sides of the addition are now of type UInt16, the addition is allowed. The output constant (twoThousandAndOne) is inferred to be of type UInt16, because it is the sum of two UInt16 values.

Comment: Alright. I must have missed it—thanks! It seems like a lot of trouble to go through. People will be conditioned to just convert in this way, so they won't think about it anyway. I can't think of another language where you need to explicitly cast integer values to get useful stuff done. Should have been a warning instead. Still, thanks!

Comment: Go has the same restriction. It avoids many kinds of errors that happen rarely, but are very difficult to debug when they do occur (usually in the field). It's why it's explicitly recommended you use just `Int` whenever possible.

Comment: I suppose except whenever you need to do 64-bit calculation? I assume that Int maps to, well, C-Int, which is 32-bit in the Mac/iOS style LP64 regime, in which case, well, you're going verbose-amok. I can see that it helps with overflow bugs, but it's something I expect a language should handle for me, i.e. by casting up to the necessary integer size if i don't specify one explicitly... which you still can do in Swift. It's a bit of a mish-mash

Comment: "I can't think of another language where you need to explicitly cast integer values to get useful stuff done." You do not seem to know many strictly statically typed functional languages. The numeric types in Swift are in fact simple: just cast directly to whatever type you want to operate with and use the appropriate operators. Use &+ if you want C/C++/Objective C like behavior, or use + if you know there will be no overflow/underflow errors. And go study Haskell, then you'll find Swift numeric type conversions almost insipid.

Answer (score 7):

```
let a: Int64 = 1500
let b: Int32 = 12349
let c = a + Int64(b)
println("The value of c is \(c)")
```