# get `(UInt8.min + UInt8.max) * 3` to console

Tags: swift

With swift, when I input this code below, I could not get the sumInt number to console?

```
    let minValue=UInt8.min
    let maxValue=UInt8.max
    let sumInt=(maxValue+minValue)*3
    println(sumInt)
```

after I change the code as below

```
    let minValue=UInt8.min
    let maxValue=UInt8.max
    let sumInt:Int=(maxValue+minValue)*3
    println(sumInt)
```

I got an error

> Could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments

how can I make it right?

Comment: This is like page 2 of the book, by the way.

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be? Your minValue will be 0 (minimum of unsigned int) and multiplying your maxValue by 3 will overflow (might crash, or maybe it will just wrap around, not sure). What are you trying to achieve? Try using smaller values. Also the compiler error might be because 3 is inferred to be Int type and can't multiply with UInt type (but not sure about that)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift: Errors when using different integer sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048334/swift-errors-when-using-different-integer-sizes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because the type you get from the sum is again a UInt8.. try

```
 let minValue=UInt8.min
    let maxValue=UInt8.max
    let sumInt:Int8=(maxValue+minValue)*3 //overflow
    println(sumInt)
```

Or

```
let minValue=UInt8.min
let maxValue=UInt8.max
let sumInt:Int=(Int)(maxValue+minValue)*3
println(sumInt)
```

But notice that the number sumInt will now be valid because its no longer a UInt8 which goes up to only 255 and it overflows in the first code snippet.